# Recognize internal storage of portable device through MTP in C#

Tags: c#, android, mobile, connection, mtp

I'm trying to develop winform(C#) application to search file from connected portable device(mobile device) using MTP.

I can get connected or disconnected status from **wndproc** method using **WM_DEVICECHANGE**.
But what I really want to develop is to cause an event when **internal storage** is created (it is able to read on window) after the deivce is connected from MTP.

So I was trying to create wndProc and input the code below in this code "if (m.Msg == UsbAlert.WM_DEVICECHANGE){ ... }"

```
         if (devType == UsbAlert.DBT_DEVTUP_VOLUME)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DBT DEVTUP VOLUME");
                DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol;
                vol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));
                Console.WriteLine(vol.dbcv_unitmask);
            }
```

But it is only can operate portable device such as USB not a mobile phone (android, ios)
There are so many codes for connecting device to windows but not for mobile phone.
**Please let me know how can set an event when internal storage is ready to scan on windows.**
Can I use WndProc function to develop this or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved by myself not using the WM_DEVTUP_VOLUME using wnd_proc fuctions.

This article make me solved the problem below.
[How to get MTP device Available Storage & Storage Capacity using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148557/how-to-get-mtp-device-available-storage-storage-capacity-using-c)

You can get storage voulme using WPD lib from windows.